# Airflow 2.4 : UpStream_Failed Issue

Tags: python, airflow

I have created a dag in airflow that generates dynamic tasks on runtime. The DAG gets the configuration from two different tables and generates the tasks accordingly. Below is the DAG:

[image]

The issue is that sometimes etl_unload_purge_configurations__1/master_data_extract_configurations__1 tasks don't execute and generate an Upstream_Failed error. Below is the code:

```
logging.info('=====>Setting Default Arguments. . .')
default_args = {
    'owner': vars["owner"],
    'depends_on_past': vars["depends_on_past"],
    'email': vars["email"],
    'email_on_failure': vars["email_on_failure"],
    'email_on_retry': vars["email_on_retry"],
    'retries': vars["retries"],
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
    }



logging.info('=====>Initiating DAG. . .')
@dag(
      max_active_runs=vars["max_active_runs"],
      schedule=vars["schedule_interval"],
      catchup= vars["catchup"],
      default_args=default_args,
      max_active_tasks =vars["max_active_tasks"],
      start_date=days_ago(2),
      render_template_as_native_obj=True
)



def DataLake_Unload_Purge():

    start=DummyOperator(task_id='Start')
    end = DummyOperator(task_id='end')

    #loop through configuration_tables
    for x, y in configuration_tables.items():
        @task.python(task_id=f"{x}")
        def Get_Configuration(rds_conn_id: str, process_type: str, config_query: str,start_date:str,end_date:str) -> List[int]:
            logging.info(f'Retreieving Configuration')
            scheduled_requests = utils.Get_Configuration(rds_conn_id=rds_conn_id, process_type=process_type,
                                                         config_query=config_query,start_date=start_date,end_date=end_date)

            logging.info(f'REQUEST SCHEDULES BEING PROCESSED: {scheduled_requests}')
            return scheduled_requests

        @task.python(task_id=f"{x}")
        def unload_data(rds_conn_id: str,redshift_conn_id:str, process_type: str, access_key: str,secret_key:str,scheduled_ids:int) -> None:
            logging.info(f'Unload Process Stared ')

            utils.unload_purge_func(rds_conn_id=rds_conn_id,redshift_conn_id=redshift_conn_id, process_type=process_type,
                                                         access_key=access_key,secret_key=secret_key,scheduled_ids=scheduled_ids)


        scheduled_ids = Get_Configuration(
            rds_conn_id=y['rds_conn_id'],
            config_query=y['query'],
            process_type=y['process_type'],
            start_date="{{ dag_run.get_previous_scheduled_dagrun().execution_date }}",
            end_date="{{ dag_run.execution_date }}"

        )

        scheduled_tasks=unload_data.partial(
            rds_conn_id=y['rds_conn_id'],
            redshift_conn_id=y['redshift_conn_id'],
            process_type=y['process_type'],
            access_key=(Variable.get("ACCESS_KEY")),
            secret_key=(Variable.get("SCRT_KEY"))
        ).expand(scheduled_ids=scheduled_ids)

        start>>scheduled_ids>>scheduled_tasks>>end
```

I am unable to find the root cause. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: do you see any lod details that you can share? under the failed task

Comment: @ozs: This issue has been fixed in Airflow 2.4.4(https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/27449)